# I 'm not able to pass arguments to python file ( google calender API)

Tags: python, api, calendar

I'm trying to execute the example file of google API ,that is the second example in this page ; [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started)

when I execute the python file from the terminal like this :

```
$ python authorized_api_cmd_line_calendar.py your_client_id your_client_secret
```

I passed the following arguments

```
$ python authorized_api_cmd_line_calendar.py *******************gnlm3tj8obddlimdbaqp7psime.apps.googleusercontent.com **********V69CImgEkHaO3zkqR
```

(without starts for sure!)
When I run the preceding command I get the following errors :

```
warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
...
...
...
authorized_api_cmd_line_calendar.py : error: unrecognized arguments : *******************gnlm3tj8obddlimdbaqp7psime.apps.googleusercontent.com **********V69CImgEkHaO3zkqR
```

I tried to pass the client_secret file instead of the preceding but no thing changed , 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by bypassing the argument handling.

It should work as written, but quick and dirty, this is what I did:

Lines 27-28 of authorized_api_cmd_line_calendar.py replaced to read:

```
# client_id = sys.argv[1]
# client_secret = sys.argv[2]                                                    
client_id = '*******************gnlm3tj8obddlimdbaqp7psime.apps.googleusercontent.com'
client_secret = '**********V69CImgEkHaO3zkqR'
```

Hope that helps.